# Best way to to have GridPane with editable numbers(a la Sudoku)? [JavaFX]

Tags: java, gridview, javafx, sudoku

I want to be able to edit the numbers, but also have them be readable and writable(via observer pattern).

Would a gridpane containing Labels be the solution? The way I have it now, the Labels aren't updated when I call setText on them.

Maybe some kind of list backing the gridview would be optimal, but I don't know how to approach that(have searched already).

Comment: You can use `TextField`, change their look using css according to your requirement.

Comment: good idea, never done that before. So right now I cannot make the textfield itself transparent right? (not the text, only the background)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextField` and change the css so that they appear as desired. Also you can set those textfields non editable which will hold initial values of suduko using

`textField.setEditable(false)`

You can use the following css to make the `TextField` transparent.

```
.text-field {
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0px ;
}
```